# Why do some formulae not translate to Array formulae?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Further to the title, the example I'm wrestling with currently is that a formula like this:

```
=IF(AND(U3<AB3,U3<500000),U3,IF(AND(U3>AB3,AB3<500000),AB3,500000))
```

Works fine, but when I try to convert it into an array it yields the same result for every cell, in this case the final number in the formula.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(E3:E>0,IF(AND(T3:T<AB3:AB,T3:T<500000),T3:T,IF(AND(T3:T>AB3:AB,AB3:AB<500000),AB3:AB,500000)),))
```

(fyi i've included a check for blank cells as an extra if function)

I'm intrigued about why that's the case. Does anybody have any ideas? I'm relatively new to array formulae and I know there are different protocols but I have attempted to include ranges properly. I suspect the ranges might be the issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(E3:E>0,
 IF((T3:T<AB3:AB)*(T3:T<500000), T3:T,
 IF((T3:T>AB3:AB)*(AB3:AB<500000), AB3:AB, 500000)), ))
```

`AND` in binary:

[image]

Comment: This worked like magic, thanks! Do if(and formulae not work with arrays? (I can only accept the answer in 10 minutes)

Comment: @FCBT `AND` and `OR` are not supported within `ARRAYFORMULA`. use multiplication for  `AND` and addition for `OR`